# EF core many to many relation violation of primary key constraint entity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to add items to test database for integration test .
These tables have many-to-many relation (I config them in database context) I want to add new record to watchlist table but AddAsync throws DbUpdate Exception

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Movies'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Movies'. The duplicate key value is (f48bd131-79ad-47bc-8cf2-1ece8ba648c2).
> The statement has been terminated.

EF thinks I want to update movie entity but I want to add item to Watchlist and link table (MovieWatchlist)

my project is base on [CleanArchitecture](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture)

```
   public class Movie
   {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string PrimaryTitle { get; set; }
        public string OriginalTitle { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Watchlist> Watchlists { get; set; }
   }

    public class Watchlist 
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    [Test]
    public static async Task ShouldRemoveMovieFromWatchlist<TEntity>()
    {
        var userId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var movieList = await GetAsync();
        var watchlist = new Watchlist { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), UserId = userId, Movies = moviesList};
        await AddAsync(watchlist);

        // Act
        var command = new RemoveMovieFromWatchlistCommand { MovieId = movieId, WatchlistId = watchlist.Id };
        var id = await SendAsync(command);
        var result = Include<Watchlist>(id,e => e.Movies);

        // Assert
        result.Should().NotBeNull();
        result.Movies.Should().HaveCount(0);
    }
```

```
    private static IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public static async Task AddAsync<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var dbSet =  context.Set<TEntity>();
        dbSet.Add(entity);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    

    public static async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAsync<TEntity>()
        where TEntity : class
    {
        using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();

        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        return await context.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
    }
```

so what can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that EF Core's change tracker is not tracking the given entities, because when you call `AddAsync()` it creates a new scope and a new `DbContext`.

I started to use the same integration testing method recently, and it's great, but the testing helper methods won't get you far without extending them quite a bit. A better way of handling `DbContext` would probably be to instantiate one per test case, instead of one per each operation.

Anyhow, one easy solution is to attach the given entities to the current `DbContext` in the same scope you're inserting the new `Watchlist`. A crude modification to your attach method implementing this change:

```cs
public static async Task AddAsync<TEntity>(TEntity entity, IEnumerable<object> attachThese = null)
where TEntity : class
{
    using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();

    if (attachThese != null)
    {
        context.AttachRange(attachThese);
    }

    var dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    dbSet.Add(entity);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

remember to add movies list to watchlist :

```cs
var watchlist = new Watchlist { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), UserId = userId, Movies = moviesList};
```

And then call it like this in your test:

```cs
await AddAsync(watchlist, movieList);
```

Let me know if it does/doesn't work.